# How to separate a column in R with unequal character lengths and without separators

Tags: r, tidyverse, tidyr

I want to separate a column which contains dates and items into two columns.

```
V1
23/2/2000shampoo
24/2/2000flour
21/10/2000poultry
17/4/2001laundry detergent
```

To this

```
V1           V2
23/2/2000    shampoo
24/2/2000    flour
21/10/2000   poultry
17/4/2001    laundry detergent
```

My problem is that there's no separation between the two. The date length isn't uniform (it's in the format of 1/1/2000 instead of 01/01/2000) so I can't separate by character length. The dataset also covers multiple years.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option would be `separate` from `tidyr`.  We specify the `sep` with a regex lookaround to split between digit and a lower case letter

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%
   separate(V1, into = c("V1", "V2"), sep="(?<=[0-9])(?=[a-z])")
#        V1                V2
#1  23/2/2000           shampoo
#2  24/2/2000             flour
#3 21/10/2000           poultry
#4  17/4/2001 laundry detergent
```

---

Or with `read.csv` after creating a delimiter with `sub`

```
read.csv(text = sub("(\\d)([a-z])", "\\1,\\2", df1$V1), 
         header = FALSE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(V1 = c("23/2/2000shampoo", "24/2/2000flour", 
      "21/10/2000poultry", 
"17/4/2001laundry detergent")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use capture groups with `tidyr::extract()`. The first group `\\d{1,2}/\\d{1,2}/\\d{4}` get the date in the format you posted, and the second group `[[:print:]]+` grabs at least one printable character.

```
library(tidyverse)

df1 %>%
  extract(V1, c("V1", "V2"), "(\\d{1,2}/\\d{1,2}/\\d{4})([[:print:]]+)")
          V1                V2
1  23/2/2000           shampoo
2  24/2/2000             flour
3 21/10/2000           poultry
4  17/4/2001 laundry detergent
```

**Data**:

```
df1 <- readr::read_csv("V1
23/2/2000shampoo
24/2/2000flour
21/10/2000poultry
17/4/2001laundry detergent")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use :

```
data <- data.frame(V1 = c("23-02-2000shampoo", "24-02-2001flour"))

library(stringr)
str_split_fixed(data$V1, "(?<=[0-9])(?=[a-z])", 2)

     [,1]         [,2]     
[1,] "23-02-2000" "shampoo"
[2,] "24-02-2001" "flour"
```

Comment: Typo: you created the data frame with `v1`, but split it with `V1`

Comment: @Gainz the same code could be used in `base R`. with `strsplit` `do.call(rbind, strsplit(as.character(data$V1), "(?<=[0-9])(?=[a-z])", perl = TRUE))`

Comment: @akrun Yes! I didn't think of it you are right. I'm just used to the ``stringr`` package since it's a lot faster on the data I work with (500+ millions of rows) than base R. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Gainz stringr wraps around `stringi` and stringi is very fast :=)

Comment: @akrun Yes it is definitively an amazing package!